# How to design WooCommerce-like admin tabs for plugin settings page?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, admin-menu

I'm working on a WooCommerce addon/plugin and created a custom admin sub page under WooCommerce menu in dashboard.

Now I am looking to add tabs and sub navigation as per the Settings page under WooCommerce.

[image: WooCommerce settings tab]

I am wondering if there is a WordPress/WooCommerce of doing it, or do I need to just replicate it using custom code?

Edit: ideally it should be on my custom admin sub page, but guidance to add a new tab to WooCommerce->Settings is also appreciated.

Comment: here is a useful links. NEW Tab -> https://www.speakinginbytes.com/2014/07/woocommerce-settings-tab/  . in product tab -> https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adding-a-section-to-a-settings-tab/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out how to do it on my custom admin page.

You can use default wordpress classes and get variable trickery like so:

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ) {
        $active_tab = $_GET[ 'tab' ];
    } // end if
?>

<h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
    <a href="?page=sandbox_theme_options&tab=display_options" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'display_options' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Display Options</a>
    <a href="?page=sandbox_theme_options&tab=social_options" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'social_options' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Social Options</a>
</h2>
```

And then wrap everything else in `if($active_tab == 'desired_option'){}` statements.

Credit: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-wordpress-settings-api-part-5-tabbed-navigation-for-settings--wp-24971